# On Hopf invariant

Tags: algebraic-topology

I didn't understand following expression from Hatcher. Let $f: S^{2n-1} \to S^{n}$. If $f$ is a constant map, then $Cf=S^{2n} \lor S^{n}$ and $H(f)=0$ since $Cf$ retracts onto $S^n$.

Answer (score 1):

$Cf$ is the cone on $f$, the quotient of $(S^{2n-1} \times [0, 1]) \cup S^n$ by the relation  that $(x, 1) \sim f(x)$ and $(x, 0) \sim (y, 0)$ for all $x, y \in S^{2n-1}$. It's not too hard to see that if $f$ is the constant map to $p \in S^n$, the quotient of $(S^{2n-1} \times [0, 1])$ by this relation is $S^{2n}$, and the sole point it shares with $S^n$ is $p$.

$H(f)$ is the Hopf degree of $f$, I'm guessing, although it could be the induced map on homology.

Is there something else that you didn't understand, or was it just the notation?